# How can I render a partial form in the index action to update boolean values for records? Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to render a partial form inside of an each do block, to update its boolean and enum values. I cannot seem to pass the id for the record to the form itself. Its failing to recognize the form object.

I'm using Rails 5.2 and latest Simple_Form. I rendered a partial in a bs 4 dropdown menu, which would only expose the boolean and enumerator attributes for the object.

index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each.with_index(1) do |post, index| %>
  <div class="card bg-light mb-3 posts-card-border-reset" style="max-width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card-header post-card-header"><span class="badge badge-purple">App</span> #<%= index %>
  <div class="dropdown dropleft" style="float: right;">
    <button class="bttn-material-circle bttn-sm bttn-default" id="dropdown_post_1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fas fa-align-justify caret-color"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu post-sub-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdown_post_1">
          <%= render 'applicant_status_update_form', local: post %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">
    <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> <%= post.user_first_name + " " + post.user_last_name %>
  </h5>
  <p class="card-text"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> <%= post.user.email %></p>
  </p>

  <div class="post-card-divider"></div>
  <small class="text-muted">
    <i class="far fa-clock"></i> <%= post.created_at.strftime('%l:%M %p %m/%d/%Y') %></small>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, :url => admin_applicant_update_application_status_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
 <div class="dropdown-item">
<span class="dropdown-header"><%= f.input :is_post_reviewed, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline %> <small>Mark As Reviewed</small></span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <div class="dropdown-item">
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li><p class="font-weight-bold">Application Status</p></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="dropdown-item">
    <span><%= f.input :status, as: :radio_buttons %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-item">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Update Status", class: 'bttn-simple bttn-md bttn-royal' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

post_application.rb

```
class PostApplication < ApplicationRecord
  include Friendlyable
  belongs_to :user

  enum status: { pending: 'pending', accepted: 'accepted', denied: 'denied' }, _prefix: :status
end
```

admin_applicants_controller

```
class AdminApplicantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def index
@posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(current_admin.posts.collect(&:post_applications).flatten).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end

  def update_application_status
    @post = PostApplication.find(params[:id])
permitted_columns = params.require(:post).permit(:is_application_reviewed, :status)
    if @post.update_attributes(permitted_columns)
      flash[:success] = "#{@post.first_name}'s Application Status Updated!"
      redirect_to admin_applicants_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "#{@post.first_name}'s failed to update! Try again"
      redirect_to admin_applicants_path
    end
  end
end
```

routes

```
  resources :admin_applicants, :only => [:index] do
    post :update_application_status
  end
```

The boolean/enum attributes should be changeable and the form should post with the updates applied.

Comment: try changing `@post` to `post` in your form. From `simple_form_for(@post,...` to `simple_form_for(post,...`

Comment: I need your folder structure

Comment: Changing my code structure now. I will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable directly to `render`, as per [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+the+default+case). In your case:

```
<%= render 'applicant_status_update_form', post: post %>
```

The following are [also available](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-The+-3Aas+and+-3Aobject+options):

```
<%= render 'applicant_status_update_form', object: post, as: 'post' %>
<%= render 'applicant_status_update_form', locals: { post: post } %>
```

All result in the same thing: making a `post` local variable available to your partial.

From there, you'll need to switch `@post` to `post` in your partial, and everything should display as desired.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on.

---

**Update based on your comment**

If you're not finding the post by ID in your update action, I think I've seen the issue: you pass the url `admin_applicant_update_application_status_path` to the form without an ID.

For a quick fix, you can use:

```
<%= simple_form_for(post, :url => admin_applicant_update_application_status_path(id: post.id), :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

Better will be to update your routes to take an ID in the `update_application_status` path. So, switch your `routes.rb` to use:

```
resources :admin_applicants, :only => [:index] do
  post 'update_application_status/:id'
end
```

And then your form to:

```
<%= simple_form_for(post, :url => admin_applicant_update_application_status_path(post.id), :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

[This section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) of the docs covers the above, if you're interested in having a read.

Hope that does it for ya!

Comment: Did this help at all @ColePhiper?

Comment: Sorry, I’m unable to find the ID. Even though the form itself loads

Comment: Ah - think I've got it @ColePhiper. I've updated my answer with this - doesn't look like you were passing the ID to the url, presumably causing `@post = PostApplication.find(params[:id])` to fail? Please see my updated answer with a solution :)

Comment: It began to work after I removed the local variable from the flash alert! Thanks

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @ColePhiper. If you're happy with the answer, please hit the tick to accept this, over on the left hand side :)